# Set JFrame icon translucent/blank

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How would I set the icon of a JFrame to be translucent/blank? I just don't want an icon.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setIcon();
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the opacity of jframe

```
 JFrame testFrame=new JFrame ();
  testFrame.setUndecorated(true);    // Frame is required to set undecorated for changing shape and transparency
  testFrame.setOpacity(0.3f);
```

Details in http://java-swings.blogspot.com/2014/09/java-swings-working-with-jframe.html

[image]

Comment: LOL, this is interesting but it doesn't really answer the question. :)